# Updating string variable in java shows 2 errors

Tags: java, android, string, variables

```
/**
 * This method is called when the order button is clicked.
 */

public void submitOrder(View view) {
    String drinkOfTheDay = "Latte";
           drinkOfTheDay = "Esperso";
           drinkOfTheDay = "Green Tea";
   displayMessage(drinkOfTheDay);
```

Error:

> - "latte":variable'drinkOfTheDay''initializer'"Latte"is redundant
> - drinkOfTheDay ,java says:The value "Esperso" assigned to 'drinkOfTheDay'is never used.

My android device just shows Green tea.

Answer (score 1):

```
   displayMessage(drinkOfTheDay);
```

The last assigned value is taken by the variable in JAVA, so the **drinkOfTheDay** should contain "Green Tea"

Answer (score 0):

`my android device just shows Green tea`.
Well, that's **expected**: what you're doing is:

1 - Creating a String variable called `drinkOfTheDay` and assigning it the value of "Latte".
2 - Change its value to "Esperso" (I guess you meant "Expresso").
3 - Change its value to "Green tea".

So, in the end, your `drinkOfTheDay` string value is "Green tea".

Answer (score 0):

Since you are assigning different values to the same variable multiple times, the value which is assigned at the latest period of time will be in the variable and the output shown is expected.

**drinkOfTheDay ,java says:The value "Esperso" assigned to 'drinkOfTheDay'is never used.**

This error is because you are just assigned it and never used it.